# Video player for playing from binary stream (byte array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, arrays

Is there any javascript/jQuery/html5 video player, which doesn't need real file to play it. I have video file stored in database(`varbinary(MAX)`) and want some player to play video with the byte array source.
Have anyone some good solution for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link that might help you.

http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/play-videos-in-aspnet-mvc-html5-using.html